# How to create varying opacity within a layer in Mapserver?

Tags: mapserver, sld

Suppose you have a mapfile containing a background layer and a layer with a lot of overlapping linestrings.

Now, for the overlapping linestrings, it might be good to visualize their density, thus at places where a lot of lines do overlap they might be drawn more "solid" than at places where only a few lines are present.

Using QGIS, for example, I can do this by just turning the layer opacity to some small value (say five percent). In Mapserver, however, setting the opacity of the layer, the opacity will just make the whole layer see through, but will not add up for each single element.

How can I archive the desired effect?

Comment: Is the linestrings layer a POINT or a LINE kind of layer? If it's a POINT or it can be converted into a POINT layer then it might be worthwhile checking out the new CLUSTER feature: http://mapserver.org/mapfile/cluster.html#cluster

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the lines should remain as lines - this is set by the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mapserver you can either set the OPACITY at the [LAYER](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html) level or for each individual [STYLE](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/style.html). A layer can have multiple styles for each of the different line types. 
This method relies on you being able to split your linestrings into different classes based on an attribute (such as year in the example below).

```
LAYER
CLASSITEM "year"
...
CLASS
  NAME "Lines"
  EXPRESSION "2010"
  STYLE
    OPACITY 70
    COLOR 178 114 1
    SIZE 15
  END # STYLE
END # CLASS
CLASS
  NAME "More Lines"
  EXPRESSION "2011"
  STYLE
    OPACITY 70
    COLOR 178 114 1
    SIZE 15
  END # STYLE
END # CLASS
END
```

If you just want one style, the solution is even simpler:

```
LAYER
...
CLASS
    NAME "Lines"
    STYLE
        OPACITY 5
        COLOR 178 114 1
        SIZE 15
    END # STYLE
END # CLASS
END
```

Comment: Thanks. While I have no attribute to cluster, your suggestion did the trick. You simply can use only one class without the expressions.

Comment: I edited your answer to accomodate the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if MapServer implements this but SLD allows you to specify the opacity of the line itself in the styling. This is different than the layer transparency setting which as you say just makes the background see through.